# How do we use php along with python in a flask project

Tags: php, python, webpage-screenshot

I am working on a flask project, wherein i am using PHP to get the screenshot. How do we use php along with python in a flask project.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use php script by running like

```
import subprocess

# if the script don't need output.
subprocess.call("php /path/to/your/script.php")

# if you want output
proc = subprocess.Popen("php /path/to/your/script.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

Reference: [Use php script in python](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-October/071973.html)

Answer (score 0):

or using python in a php-script:

```php
<?php
    exec("python my_pyton.py");
?>
```